# Rewrite without <xsl:for-each>; select all text separated by spaces; dropping text with attribute

Tags: xslt

I have the following XSL working but there should be a way to rewrite it without using the xsl:for-each element.  I need to take an arbitrary block of XML, drop all elements that have a 'drop' attribute and concatenate the remaining text with spaces without adding extra spaces at the end or end of the concatenated text.

I should say that the only part of the XML I can key off of is the 'drop' attribute.  I cannot key off of any of element names like 'testing', 'catalog', 'book', etc.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[not(@drop)]/text()">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XML I've been testing with:

```
<testing>
    <text drop="meta">Drop this meta</text>
    <catalog>
        <book id="bk101">
            <text drop="stuff">Drop this stuff</text>
            <title ti="Full Title">XML Developer\ts Guide</title>
            <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
        </book>
    </catalog>
</testing>
```

and the valid output:

```
XML Developer   s Guide Gambardella, Matthew
```

edit:  As pointed out by @michael.hor257k it assumed the XML will not have any [mixed content](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_mixed.asp)

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?

Comment: I'm still learning but every language has preferred idioms.   My understanding is that XSLT prefers a push or pull model to what I wrote.   My other goal is expand my knowledge; I want to know how the push model would work.

Comment: "*My understanding is that XSLT prefers a push or pull model to what I wrote.*" No, there are pros and cons to both methods.

Comment: You need to understand *when* and *why* people advocate the push model. It's primarily because it provides *potential for change*: the ability to adapt and reuse the code to meet different requirements from those originally envisaged. Rewriting the code to use templates instead of for-each achieves nothing unless it is part of a process to improve the modularity and reusability of the code.

Comment: I fully agree with Dr. Kay. Still, the transformation in my answer is completely in "push" style, and even more importantly, it differs from the other two answers in that it produces the correct result on any source XML document. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin Honnen pointed out in his deleted answer, in XSLT 2.0 this could be accomplished by a single `xsl:value-of` instruction. Here's his answer, with a minor correction by me:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="//*[not(@drop) and text()]" separator=" "/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, this assumes no mixed content in the source XML (as I believe the other answers do too). If this were a requirement, you could use :

```
<xsl:value-of select="string-join(//*[not(@drop)]/text(), ' ')" />
```

instead.

Comment: This works with both Dimitre's more complicated example and the original xml provided in the question.

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vFirst" select="(//*[not(@drop)]/text())[1]"/>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(@drop)]/text()[not(. is $vFirst)]">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ',  .)"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="*[@drop]/text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided source XML document**:

```
<testing>
    <text drop="meta">Drop this meta</text>
    <catalog>
        <book id="bk101">
            <text drop="stuff">Drop this stuff</text>
            <title ti="Full Title">XML Developer     s Guide</title>
            <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
        </book>
    </catalog>
</testing>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

`XML Developer     s Guide Gambardella, Matthew`

**When applied on more irregular XML documents, like this:**

```
<testing>
    <text drop="meta">Drop this meta</text>
    <catalog>
        <book id="bk100"><title ti="Full Title">JSON Developer     s Guide</title></book>
        <book id="bk101">
            <text drop="stuff">Drop this stuff</text>
            <title ti="Full Title">XML Developer     s Guide</title>
            <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
        </book>
    </catalog>
</testing>
```

**the transformation again produces the correct, wanted result:**

`JSON Developer     s Guide XML Developer     s Guide Gambardella, Matthew`

Do note that **the solutions in the other two answers don't produce the correct result** when applied on the above XML document.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for (works also with XSLT 1.0)

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

  <xsl:template match="*[not(@drop) and normalize-space(text()) != '']" >
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Update:
As mentioned in comment the use of position() was **not** right because it checks the position in the current node-list and not in the document. 
Therefore try this (still XSLT 1.0 solution):

```
 <xsl:variable name="last" select="generate-id((//*[not(@drop)]/text())[last()])" /> 
 <xsl:template match="*[not(@drop)]/text()[normalize-space() != '']" >
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:if test="generate-id() != $last">
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()" />
```

Comment: That works; I had to add the   xsl:strip-space elements="*"   back into the XSL so the trailing space didn't get tacked on to the end of the output.

Comment: Hmm `<xsl:template match="text()" />` should ignore any text which is not matched by other templates. Btw. please consider to select a answer as valid or vote up if it was what you are looking for.

Comment: The use of `position()` here is incorrect. What is wanted is not the position of the matched node in the node-list ! Just try this with a slightly more-complicated XML document, where all text-nodes to be processed are not siblings -- for example with the 2nd XML document from my answer.

Comment: @hr_117 as mentioned by Dimitre this doesn't work with more complicated XML.   Running the XSL on his more complicated example does not add the space between all of the text values.    `JSON Developer     s GuideXML Developer     s Guide Gambardella, Matthew`